# JPA - как сделать возвращаемый объект снова обычным POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    Person person = personService.getPerson(1L);
    System.out.println(person);

    Person person1 = new Person();
    System.out.println(person1);
}
```

Где Person  это стандартно проаннотированная model с @Entity, @Table, полями @Column и т.д.  Одно из полей - коллекция с LAZY инициализацией. 
Так вот,  в случае person1  -  я получу в распечатке эту коллекцию null - никто не возмущается лейзи или нет эта коллекция.  А в случае с person  мы конечно же получим

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection
```

то есть ,  ну я плохо уже понимаю этот  момент,  за person еще "кто-то" следит,  хотя это вроде как уже detached объект от persistence context.

Вопрос - что надо сделать с person, чтобы его sout   дал просто null на коллекцию. И можете подсказать где вообще об этом можно подробно почитать

Сам сервис  **personService** дергает метод у репозитория **getPersonByIdWithoutFetch**

```
 @Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p JOIN FETCH p.roles r WHERE p.id =:personId")
    Person getPersonByIdWithFetch(Long personId);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.id =:personId")
    Person getPersonByIdWithoutFetch(Long personId);
}
```

Person entity

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "persons")
    public class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;

        @ManyToMany(cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
        }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "person_roles",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
        )
        private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Выложите тот метод где у вас выдается ошибка. Вы используете Spring или просто Hibernate?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду когда пишите >сделать возвращаемый объект снова обычным POJO?

Comment: @Z.John я конечно выразился не по научному.  Имею ввиду, что я вот  получил ссылку person   после запроса из repository  и  теперь я хочу обращаться как вот с объектом без всякой привязки к jpa / hibernate.  Чтобы,  если коллекция не проинициализировалась ,  не было попыток  ее проинициализировать.   То есть разорвать полностью связь с jpa/hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

В момент когда вы делаете  `System.out.println(person);` происходит вызов `person.toString()` именно в этот момент запрашивается ваше `Lazy` поле. Но не может проинициализироваться и возникает ошибка LazyInitializationException

Чтоб этого избежать, можно пометить метод аннотацией @Transactional, или в параметрах конфигурации задать свойство hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true.

Есть статья на эту тему здесь https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/

Comment: ,  вопрос в другом заключается )   Если прям очень  бытовым языком - я отдаю себе отчет что забираю person с пустой коллекцией roles.  И вот  когда я все же обращаюсь потом к этой коллекции  - не надо ничего пытаться извлечь , инициализировать  - просто верните мне null и все.  Как будто  я получил person из new Pesron()

Comment: он вам его и вернул, вызов коллекции произошел когда вы вызвали метод toString() на объекте. Если посмотрите в отладчике, то до этого момента там и есть null.

Comment: переопределите метод toString() в вашей сущности - это правило хорошего тона, думаю ваша проблема с этим уйдет

Comment: тем не менее мне кидается эксепш.  Вот я хотел бы чтобы не было никаких эксепшенов  -  то есть НИКАКОЙ  связи  с jpa/hibernate.   Чтобы sout вывел roles = null   и все .  Как в случае когда я сам создал person1

Comment: а можете выложить метод toString() сущности Person

Comment: Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", roles=" + roles +
                '}';
    }

Comment: как я понимаю roles и есть та коллекция?

Comment: да,   и я хочу чтобы было  просто roles=null  -  как будто  не было никаких  хибернейтов и джпа )

Comment: Такого не будет, при первом обращении к полю, hibernate пытается его инициализировать. Если он вам выдаст null то это искажение информации сущности, так как в сущности роли есть- согласны? Потребителей классов не должно волновать происходит инициализация в отложенном виде или сразу. И если кто-то извне попросил информацию, то он должен получить корректный ответ.

Comment: однако  если я делаю person1 = new Person()  -  то никто не беспокоитcя, что у нас не проинициализированна коллекция roles и соответственно не пытается ее проинициализировать.

Comment: Потому что если вы делаете new Person() вы создаете новую сущность , никто не знает с какими ролями ее вязать, это можете знать только вы - как разработчик.

Comment: можно сделать  какие-то операции  с person,  чтобы  peson.getRoles()  был абсолютно эквивалентен person1.getRoles() и просто выдал мне null ?  Как отвязать хибернейт от person  ?  Если это невозможно , ну ок,  жаль. А если возможно то как ? ))

Comment: не понимаю зачем, но можете написать так `String toString() { return "Person{" + "id=" + id + ", username='" + username + '\'' + ", password='" + password + '\'' + ", roles=null" + '}';` так будет всегда выдавать 'roles=null', или как вариант сделайте другой метод вывода сущности на печать без roles и вызывайте его

Comment: можно сделать какие-то операции с person, чтобы peson.getRoles()  - нет

Comment: затем что я могу извлечь person с Fetch  и сделать "где-то там в коде" sout  со всеми его полями, включая roles.  Но также я хочу   извлечь person  без подгрузки roles,  потом "где-то в коде"  сделать sout и  чтобы мне распечатались его id, name, pass  и roles  ,   roles будет просто  null.  Но я понимаю что это выдаст мне закономерный эксепшн.  И я хочу узнать  - можно ли как-то схитрить - как бы сделать так чтобы джпашная аннотация LAZY  была как бы не при делах,  что pesron это как бы ПРОСТО объект с ПРОСТО полями  и я ПРОСТО получаю roles = null   .

Comment: еще раз, пока вы целенаправленно не будете обращаться к полю roles оно и не будет инициализироваться. А когда оно вам понадобится вы вызовите gerRoles(), и hibernate вам подтянет коллекцию. Сейчас вы в это уперлись потому что для теста вызвали метод toString(), а в этом методе есть обращение к этому полю. По среди кода вы же не будете вызывать постоянно toString(). Можете сделать отдельно метод toStringNoRoles() который будет возвращать строку без ролей для печати.

Comment: "А когда оно вам понадобится вы вызовите gerRoles(), и hibernate вам подтянет коллекцию."  - в том и вопрос как  отключить попытки Hibernate подтянуть коллекцию и вместо этого просто выдать null

Comment: никак, просто не вызывайте getRoles

Comment: костыльно можно вот так например,  но мне кажется можно это иначе делать                           Person person = personService.getPerson(1L);
  person.setRoles(null);
  System.out.println(person);  Потому что в этом  участке я получается должен уже знать что коллекция не инициализированна

Comment: Плохая идея, потому что если вы это сделаете в транзакционном методе то хибернэйт это сохранит, и ваши связи с ролями все удалятся

Comment: Если вам так принципиален этот момент вы всегда можете отказаться от использования хибернэйт и написать свою орм ;)

Comment: подразумевается что после получения person -  мы во вне сессий,  транзакций и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

После выполнения Person person = personService.getPerson(1L); объект  person автоматически помещается в кэш персистности и Hibernate следит за всеми объектами, которые в нем находятся. Для того, чтобы вывести объект из кэша персистности можно сделать em.detach(person); (при этом в БД не идут никакие update и пр.) и тогда person будет вне компетенций Hibernate. Содержимое кэша можете посмотреть с помощью [класса-утилиты](http://konopkomikl.ru/2017/06/20/hibernate-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-first-level-persistence-context-cache/). Функцию showSessionCaсhe8( session, 1 ) нужно вызвать до и после detach. В консоль будет выводиться также информация и о коллекции roles объекта person.